# Programmatically change an HTML Tags Angle Bracket to `&lt;` Text Character

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I need to convert some HTML to text and show the HTML tags as code, in other words have a `<div>` show with the angle brackets and appear on screen as `<div>`. I know to do this I have to switch the angle brackets to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Is there anyway of doing this programmatically with JavaScript? I've included some pseudo code below in terms of how you'd do this is if it was a string, but I need to find out how to convert the HTML tags to strings?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/KKpqoww

```js
// PSEUDO CODE

var codeHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('code-html')

for (var i = 0; i < codeHTML.length; i+=1) {

    codeHTML[i].replace('<', '&lt;')
}
```

```html
<code class="code-html"><div></code>
Hi
<code class="code-html"></div></code>
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this way ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.code-html').forEach(codeHTML=>{
  codeHTML.innerHTML = codeHTML.innerHTML.replace(/</g,'&lt;')
})
```

```css
.code-html {
    display: block;
    background-color:lightblue;
    white-space: pre;
  }
```

```html
<code class="code-html"><div> 
    Hi
</div>
</code>
<br>
<h5>another example to show preservation of indentation (partial copy of Bootstrap code)</h5>
<code class="code-html"><div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>30 users included</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</code>
<br>
<h5>other example with CSS code and elastic-tabstops preservation</h5>
<code class="code-html">.code-html {
  display          : block;
  background-color : lightblue;
  white-space      : pre;
}
</code>
```

**Remarks:**
- `element.textContent = element.innerHTML` doesn't respect line returns.
- `element.innerText = element.innerHTML` works almost well, but it adds `<br>` when it has line breaks and it doesn't respect the white space used to indent code, which can be a problem if you want to preserve in copy and paste for the user. (I use css `white-space: pre;` to respect line breaks, and indentation spaces)

Comment: I would say maybe `.innerText` is superior for the fact that it includes line breaks. It all depends what you want and I would think for most use cases preserving line breaks would be optimal. Also `.textContent`'s functionality is documented and seems to work in practice. I think there may be some bias at play here.

Comment: @JonathanGray there is also the question of preserving spaces useful for indentation  ( and the `innerHTML` method also respect line breaks without adding a `<br>` tag )

Comment: There seems to be no benefit to using `.innerHTML` over `.innerText` in either regard. In fact using `.innerHTML` in this manner could result in unforeseen consequences (for example there is reason to believe using it could cause the code to fail at least one automated review process).

Comment: @JonathanGray  finally, with the help of css from my code, I agree to grant you one is not absolutely better than the other, but I can hardly imagine what character code could cause a damage on this use of innerHTML  with the replace used ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with the help of css from my code". However to be honest I do believe `.innerText` is superior for the fact that it just works, especially without having to run a replace on it beforehand. If you were really that concerned about the line breaks you could always remove them retroactively, or beforehand if they're entirely unnecessary. In fact `.innerHTML` is more complex because it is actually expecting HTML, so using it unnecessarily like this really doesn't even make much sense.

Comment: @JonathanGray look again at my snippet, I added 2 example showing the interest of preserving the spaces characters, this can only be done with css code.

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't. That is entirely irrelevant to the argument of `.innerHTML` vs `.innerText`. The only CSS code required is the `white-space` one and I originally considered that too obvious to even put in my answer. The question isn't about formatting, after all.

Answer (score 2):

try to get contents using **element.innerHTML** & assign those values to the elements using **element.innerText** or by **element.textContent**. Now your desired tags will be converted into strings.

Comment: I'm only upvoting this answer out of all others (excluding my own) because it encourages a proper solution for the issue at hand.

Comment: @MisterJojo It seems to work fine for me. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think setting `.innerText` with the HTML string is what you're looking for. You can get this string with `.innerHTML`. Setting `.innerText` is the safest option when working with (unsanitised) user input.

```js
document.getElementById('output').innerText = document.getElementById('input').innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id=input><span>This is a test</span></div>
<div id=output></div>
```

The following code is just for completeness:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.code-html').forEach(e => {
  e.innerText = e.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
.code-html {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<code class="code-html"><div>
Test 1
Test  2
Test 3
</div></code>
Hi
<code class="code-html"><div>
Test 4
 Test 5
Test 6
</div></code>
```

**Worth noting:**

"If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be answered in 1 term, "ELEMENT.outerHTML"
What I do, is that I get the element, then select its outerHTML term, and declare its value to the value your replace function returns

However I am quite interested in how the `&lt;` shows the html code, it's crazy, call me up if u got any more **JavaScript** logic questions

```js
//CODE

var codeHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('code-html');

for (var i = 0; i < codeHTML.length; i+=1) { //all changed code is in this loop
    codeHTML[i].outerHTML = codeHTML[i].outerHTML.replace('<', '&lt;'); //done
}
```

```html
<code class="code-html"><div></code>
Hi
<code class="code-html"></div></code>
```